# When is the template (.tpl) rendered for an Ext JS Component?

Tags: templates, extjs

I am trying to inject another component into an element that is rendered by the template of another Coomponent..but in the afterrender event, the template is yet to be rendered so the call to Ext.get(el-id) returns null: `TypeError el is null`.

```
   tpl: 
    new Ext.XTemplate(
      '<tpl for=".">',
        '<ul>',
          '<li class="lang" id="cultureSelector-li"></li>',
        '</ul>',

      '</tpl>'
      ),

  listeners: {
    afterrender: {
      fn: function (cmp) {
        console.log(Ext.get('cultureSelector-li')); // < null :[
        Ext.create('CultureSelector', { 
          renderTo: 'cultureSelector-li' 
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

So when can I add this component so that the element is targeting has been created in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong things - apparently we should be using the render* configs for this type of thing (so what are the`tpl` & `data` configs for?)

Here's a working fiddle provided for me from the sencha forums:

http://jsfiddle.net/qUudA/10/

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the component that you are working with.  For example, the Data Grid View has a "viewready" event that would suite your needs, and depending what you are attempting, the "boxready" function could work for combo box (only the first render though).  Other than that, you can either go up through the element's parent classes searching for the XTemplate render function being called (might be in the layout manager) and extend it to fire an event there, or risk a race condition and just do it in a setTimeout() call with a reasonable delay.

Comment: Its a bog-standard `Ext.Component`. The setTimeout() idea doesn't feel right

Comment: it appears the .tpl is used by the .update method of AbstractComponent, but I havent yet been able to track when and when is calling .update

Comment: apparently it's not called. wondering if anything needs to be prompted to trigger it. i was basing this work on this post http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?114317-Button-In-a-Template&s=f9b66e28536058daf71f670e1438d7df

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do the work myself. So, I now have the template as a property called `theTpl`, and then rendered it in `beforerender`, and then i was able to get a handle on the element in `afterrender`. This seems wholly counter-intuitive, does anyone have any insight?

```
beforeRender: {
      fn: function (me) {
        me.update(me.theTpl.apply({}));
      }
    },
```

**edit** in fact I just extended Component thus:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TemplatedComponent', {
  extend: 'Ext.Component',
  alias: 'widget.templatedComponent',
  template: undefined,
  beforeRender: function () {
    var me = this;
    var template = new Ext.XTemplate(me.template || '');
    me.update(template.apply(me.data || {}));
    me.callParent();
  }
})
```

...`template` accepts an array of html fragments